# Android PayPalPayment : invalid long

Tags: java, android, paypal

Tengo un error en `android studio`, mi código es:

```
private void ProcessPayment() {
   montoPagar = montoTotal.getText().toString();
    PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(montoPagar)),"$","USD",PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT,payPalPayment);
    startActivityForResult(intent,PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

cuando voy a correrlo esta linea

```
PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(montoPagar)),"$","USD",PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
```

es la que me ocasiona el error que dice invalid long...

[image: ERROR]
Alguna referencia, seria genial

Comment: Al parecer la variable `montoPagar` tiene el valor de `550 USD` que es un string y no un long.  Que es lo que te retorna `montoTotal.getText()` ?

Comment: Si, si es un string...

Comment: Pero porque te retorna `USD`, acaso lo estas concatenando?

Comment: Me retorna: 55.0 USD

Comment: Puedes mostrar el codigo donde retorna ese valor?

Comment: El extrae ese valor de un request

Comment: Andrea, Java no sabe como parsear "55.0 USD" porque no es un numero valido. Tenes que quitar del string todo lo que no sea numero.

Comment: @AndreaValentina no necesitas definir en el EditText  montoTotal el tipo de moneda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas tratando de convertir la cadena "55.0 USD" a Long lo cual es incorrecto, por esta razón obtienes `NumberFormatException`.

No tienes que definir el tipo de moneda en tu `EditText` `montoTotal`, ya que esto lo estas definiendo al instanciar [PayPalPayment(BigDecimal amount,
                     String **currencyCode**,
                     String shortDescription,
                     String paymentIntent)](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-Android-SDK/com/paypal/android/sdk/payments/PayPalPayment.html#PayPalPayment-java.math.BigDecimal-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Actualmente estas definiendo "USD":

```
 PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(montoPagar)),"$","USD",PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
```

---

Para solucionar esto, debes escribir únicamente el monto dentro de `montoTotal`.

También puedes validar extrayendo únicamente el valor numérico del texto escrito en el `EditText` `montoTotal`:

```
   montoPagar  = montoPagar.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

Este sería el código con la validación:

```
private void ProcessPayment() {
   montoPagar = montoTotal.getText().toString();
   montoPagar  = montoPagar.replaceAll("\\D+","");//*Obtiene solo el valor numerico.
    PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(montoPagar)),"$","USD",PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT,payPalPayment);
    startActivityForResult(intent,PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

También puedes definir en tu `EditText` que este solo acepte números, estableciendo la propiedad:

```
android:inputType = "numberPassword"
```

Comment: Gracias, lo logre solucionar extrayendo solo el valor numérico.